# node-debug does not break and shows no code

Tags: node.js, debugging, node-debugger

I'm trying to use `node-debug` to debug my CLI node script.  According to everything I've read, I should simply be able to run my script with `node-debug`, which will start the script with `--debug-brk`, and open my browser to the `node-inspector` page.

This all seems to be working fine.  I see no output from my script (which indicates the --debug-brk is working), my browser opens, it is connected to `node-inspector`, and if I kill `node-debug`, the inspector shows it gets disconnected.

But the inspector interface is empty.  There's no code.  No stack trace.  Nothing.

There aren't a lot of options to `node-debug`, and none of them look like they would fix the problem I'm having.

```
node-debug myscript.js
```

**output**

```
debugger listening on port 5858
Node Inspector is now available from http://127.0.0.1:8080/?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858
Debugging `myscript.js`
```

**inspector Dev console**

```
Assertion failed: Unknown experiment canvasInspection
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createSetting' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the legacy debugger, which had a somewhat rickety foundation to begin with and has since fallen out of sync with what Chrome uses for communication and has been deprecated for a while.

You should instead use the newer [built-in inspector](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector) via the `--inspect` flag.

```
node --inspect myscript.js
```

There is a userland package, [inspect-process](https://github.com/jaridmargolin/inspect-process), which makes the experience even nicer and works around some potential problems you may run into.

### More Resources

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

https://blog.risingstack.com/how-to-debug-nodej-js-with-the-best-tools-available/